# Lambda : Is any Batch processing scheduler available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

Problem : Fetch 2000 items from Dynamo DB and process(Create a POST req from 100 items) it batch by batch (Batch size = 100).

Question : Is there anyway that I can achieve it from any configuration in AWS.

PS : I've configured a cron schedule to run my Lambda function. I'm using Java. I've made multi-threaded application which synchronously does so, but this eventually increases my computation time drastically.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/batch/ how about looking into AWS batch ? I don't know after processing what happens to your data (I mean where does it go - back to dynamodb or to some external system) but still can look into this

Comment: batch service is not available in US-West .. Also, I have gone through this .. This does not seems to be right one for this ..                                          PS:The result of POST request is to be saved in another DynamoDB ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and thinking of solving it in following way. Please let me know if you try it.

1. Schedule Job to fetch N items from DynamoDB using Lambda function
2. Lambda function in #1 will submit M messages to SQS to process each
   item and trigger lambda functions, in this case it should call
   lambda functions M times  Each lambda function will process request
   given in the message

In order to achieve this you need to schedule an event via CloudWatch, setup SQS and create lambda function triggered by SQS events.

Honestly, I am not sure if this is price effective but it should be working. Assuming your fetch size is so low, this should be reasonable.

Also you can try using SNS in this case you don't need to worry about SQS message polling.