# How to get DynamoDB data in batches?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Is there any way to get the DynamoDB data in batches.

I want to fetch 2000 items from Dynamo DB but in batches, like 100 records per minute and feed it to the lambda function.

I've tried AWS batch, but it doesn't seems to be fruitful.

Comment: The Scan API call will naturally limit the number of items returned in a single operation and will yield a LastEvaluatedKey value that you can pass it on the subsequent call to continue the Scan. You can dictate when the next call to Scan takes place. Would that suffice?

Comment: If lambda is your concern, the default batch size is 100 when the source event is DynamoDB stream!

Comment: @franklinsijo a DynamoDB stream isn't the same thing as running a specific query and getting the results in batches.

Comment: How is this question not a duplicate of your previous question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924179/lambda-is-any-batch-processing-scheduler-available

Comment: If I set default batch size is 100 than it will return the first 100 items. I want 1-100, 101-199 .... 901-1000..